# AS3/XML/FLASH: Finding the attribute based on the value of the element

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash

I have XML similar to this:

```
var listXML:XML = <list>
    <name date="18/07/2013">ALPHA</name>
    <name date="15/06/2012">ALLANI</name> // <--- Get this date
    <name date="06/03/2009">FLANDES</name>    
</list>;
```

Is it possible to get the date based on the name? If I have the name `"ALLANI"` in an input text called `theName`, how can I get the "15/06/2012" date value ?

Comment: You are probably going to need a loop.

Comment: no need in loop , only `xpath`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are:

```
listXML..name.(text()=="ALLANI").@date;
```

So:

```
trace( listXML..name.(text()=="ALLANI").@date );
```

prints `15/06/2012`.

Answer (score 0):

you should use XPath- give it a look- http://www.tizag.com/xmlTutorial/xpathattribute.php

Comment: You could use XPath through a third-party library, but the ActionScript native method is E4X (used in Cherniv's answer). http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e72.html

Comment: Thanks DasDas and Lars!